# Replace Radio Button with Label?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep clicking on the unchecked radio button label "Habit", but it won't become checked. Why is that when the HTML version works?

[image]

```
<% Challenge::CATEGORY.each do |c| %>
  <%= f.radio_button(:category, c, :class => "date-format-switcher", checked: (c=='goal')) %>
  <%= label(c, c) %>
<% end %>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="goal" checked="checked" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_goal">
<label for="goal_goal">Goal</label>

<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="habit" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_habit">
<label for="habit_habit">Habit</label>
```

**css**

```
  input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
      border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

**challenge.rb**

```
CATEGORY = ['goal', 'habit']
```

I followed this [JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LgT4A/).

### Update

Using the @Wowsk answer as a guide, I tried to make the ruby output the appropriate html via incorporating `:category` with `<%= label(c, c) %>`. It hasn't worked with such attempts as, `<%= label(category: c, c) %>`, `<%= label(:category(c, c)) %>` or `<%= label(category: c, category: c) %>`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that you were using the `for` attribute wrong.

The `for` attribute is the element you want it for id.

Change the for value to the previous input's id and it should work like a charm.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
      border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="goal" checked="checked" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_goal">
<label for="challenge_category_goal">Goal</label>

<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="habit" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_habit">
<label for="challenge_category_habit">Habit</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Wowsk for the big help! I get the logic now but do you know how I can produce that HTML output with the ruby code I have?

Comment: I don't know Ruby at all, but I can try...What is the variable that is setting your id for the radio button?

Comment: I think it's automatically set as part of hierarchy. goal is part of category which is part of challenge. Yea I should know this, but I'll keep trying on my end too.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't think I can help anymore. I have never touched Ruby.

Comment: No problemo. Thanks for trying!